# PC boots fine, but motherboard speaker will not beep with HDMI cord in GPU

Tags: motherboard, bios, hdmi, gpu

I noticed a while ago that my motherboard speaker simply would not beep whenever I booted my PC. It did when I first assembled it, and for a few weeks after. It didn't really bother me considering everything worked absolutely fine.

It's starting to bother me now as there IS a beep whenever my HDMI cable is plugged into the onboard port rather than the graphics card. I've no idea whether or not I should be concerned, or if it's normal for this to happen.

As a side note, another thing I've noticed is that I'm completely unable to get to the BIOS. Once I press the power button, the first screen I see is the Windows login screen. I have not seen screen where it asks if you would like to enter the BIOS for quite a while. I'm not super stressed about this, but I did want to change a setting there. I'm unsure if this is due to my monitor going in sleep mode and waking up too late, or if it's just a problem I'm unaware about.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the beep. But, if the system is UEFI then it can be hard to boot into BIOS settings with a modern OS. You need to press and hold SHIFT when restarting Windows to get to the startup menu and choose to configure UEFI settings.

Comment: If that's the same as selecting 'advanced startup' and selecting the 'UEFI Firmware' option, it does nothing but restart like normal. I'll try again while holding shift this time though.

Comment: No luck, brought me to the same screen. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I also tried doing it using my onboard graphics. It rebooted, and they I had no display. I switched the cable over to the graphics card, and still no display. This only  happens when I attempt to access the UEFI settings with the onboard graphics plugged in.